# ASP.Net Calling Site.Master method from web page not working

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, master-pages

I saw on several web pages how to interface to a public method defined in a master file from a web page call behind code that uses that master file.

(I am using ASP.Net 4.0 on Visual Studio 2012.)

The procedure is (copied from article):

> Make sure the function is accessible to the page (i.e. declared
>   public), and use the MasterType declaration in the ContentPage:
>
> ```
> <%@ Page .... %> 
> <%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/masterpage.master" %>
> ```
>
> In the page, use Page.Master.MyFunction() to access the function. 
>   *Note: before being able to access the function, you'll need to save & build.

The problem is that I do not see the method.  Here is what I have:

Web Page (stored in /MyFolder, so /MyFolder):

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Logout.aspx.cs" Inherits="BvCorpMain.Candidates.Logout" %>
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="/SiteMasters/Site.Master" %>
```

Site.Master CS file (stored in /SiteMasters folder):

```
public void UpdateUserBlocksToCookie()
{
}
```

When I go into the code behind for the logout page and in a method I type in "Page.Master.", I do not see my method.

Comment: Is it as simple as your virtual path is missing the tildé `~` character, so it should be `VirtualPath="~/SiteMasters/Site.Master"`

Comment: No, I tried that.  The problem that I have with ~, which Microsoft inserts automatically, is that it means relative and that is not always correct.  I ran into problems, whose solution was to remove ~ and just reference off of the root of the domain.

Answer (score 0):

Your page is inheriting from System.Web.UI.Page, which only knows that its master page is of type System.Web.UI.MasterPage. If you are making modifications to a child class of MasterPage, then you need to cast the Page.Master property to your child class.

```
public class MyPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public new MyMaster Master { get { return base.Master as MyMaster; } }
    public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Master.MyMasterPageFunction();
    }
}
public class MyMaster : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    public void MyMasterPageFunction()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems that Microsoft has a bug.  It must have been rebuilding the solution along with closing out of VS2012 and restarting it solved the problem.  You did educate me.  Thank you.  The code that you wrote, though, will not build.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer did educate me, however I believe the resolution was to restart VS2012, maybe cleaning the solution and rebuilding did not hurt.  Either way.

Microsoft adds in the following code automatically to the .aspx.designer.cs file.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Master property.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Auto-generated property.
    /// </remarks>
    public new MyNamespace.Site Master {
        get {
            return ((BvCorpMain.Site)(base.Master));
        }
```

The previous answer conflicts with this definition.  Also, the previous answer of MyMaster, although granting access does not give (automatically at least) to needed form information.  I checked.  Using the existing master file is the cleanest.

The definition for the master.cs file is:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public partial class Site : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
```

As you can see, Microsoft did give access to MyNamespace.Site, which is what I needed, with "Master.".

I did not think to check the .aspx.designer.cs file for that definition, when I was having the problems.  Possibly the definition was lacking and got added later, when either I rebuilt or did a save, which I had previously done, or whatever.

Knowing the addition does simplify things, as I can add that in manually if it does not exist using that construct.

Comment: Must be a VS2012 thing. Previously you had to cast those objects manually.